# Why can LaTeX not find the pdf-file when I leave out the file ending, while there is only an tex-file alternative?

Tags: windows, includegraphics, miktex2.9

I am puzzled again, as this used to work in the past, but does not anymore. I am performing an out of source build of a set of LaTeX documents, meaning I call LaTeX in a target folder with the source being somewhere different. However in relation with `\graphicspath` there seems to be an issue if I leave out the file endings in the `\includegraphics` call. As this might be OS related, I am using Windows 10 with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 21.12.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.14)

This is my folder and file structure:

```
.
├── Documentation
│   └── MyDocument.tex
├── DocumentationBuild
├── Precompile
│   └── MyPrecompile.tex
└── Buildscript.bat
```

With the file `MyPrecompile.tex` being any sort of TeX-graphic:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) rectangle ++ (5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My document beeing `MyDocument.tex` referring to the precompile without file ending, but expecting the PDF to be loaded:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{../Precompile/}}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{MyPrecompile}
\end{document}
```

And this is the batch script `Buildscript.bat` being called from the root folder:

```
cd DocumentationBuild
pdflatex ../Precompile/MyPrecompile.tex
pdflatex ../Documentation/MyDocument.tex
cd ..
```

You might ask, why I am using the line `\graphicspath{{../Precompile/}}`, well this is for people that manually build the files in place and still want to compile `MyDocument`.

The problem with this setup is, that it leads to `` ! LaTeX Error: File `MyPrecompile' not found. ``, but when I either remove the `\graphicspath` or write `\includegraphics{MyPrecompile.pdf}` it works and hence I would like to know, what is going wrong here?

---

### Simplification

I was not sure initially, if this was solely a problem of `\includegraphics` so I overcomplicated the topic, I am sorry. I restructured the setup so you do not need to think about out of source builds or the batch script anymore. This is the folder setup:

```
.
├── Folder1
│   └── image.pdf
├── Folder2
│   └── image.tex
└── MyDocument.tex
```

This is the `MyDocument.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./Folder2/}{./Folder1/}}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{image} %%%Problem can be solved by adding .pdf
\end{document}
```

And the `image.tex` remains the same, what I checked is: It has to be `.tex`, if you change the extension, the problem will vanish, too.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill (0,0) rectangle ++ (5cm,5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the view point of `MyDocument.tex` the file `MyPrecompile.pdf` is in `./Precompile/` not `../Precompile/`. It is seldomly a good idea to compile relatively like this as things gets confusing real fast.

Comment: what you describe sounds slightly odd but it's almost never a good idea to do `pdflatex ../Precompile/MyPrecompile.tex`  you are showing `\includegraphics` here but `\input` and `\include` will have similar issues that they are all relative to the process working directory not to the file and so it is very hard to make portable multi-file documents that are called this way. I would certainly re-arrange your bat file to run pdflatex in each document directory then move the generated pdf to the final locations.

Comment: While I agree on your suggestions, the design of the build was done in the past and as I have written it used to work in an earlier version, hence I was looking for an easy fix before refactoring everything, but will probably have to look into that.
@daleif this is true, but have a look on the batch script, it builds both files in DocumentationBuild and hence the graphicspath is not needed for this sort of build alltogether. And also if you just add .pdf it will work, so the folder itself is not the issue.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle of course, this is the case in this repository as well and hence the situation is more complicated and we also copy the required files to the build folder to circumvent this. But I still don't get why LaTeX isn't able to find the PDF, but if you remove the ````graphicspath``` or add the ```.pdf``` file ending it does.

Comment: I'm not saying you cannot compile relatively, but it has some consequenses that one have to know. Especially regarding relative includes

Comment: @daleif reading your comment again and checking my question I recognized I had the folder structure described incorrectly. I corrected it including the batch file and now everything is correct, but still leads to the same error.

Comment: I may see if I can re-create the directory structure and test over the weekend but it's tricky to support this and not impossible a case missed and almost always it's a really bad idea to call the main document from another directory so it does not come up often in practice.

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the tex file is found when graphicspath is used with no extension but then rejected as it's not a known extension, arguably it should then move on to other options and eventually find the pdf but the details are tricky here. Just not putting yourself in this situation would be simplest.

Comment: The problem is that `pdflatex` will write the PDF on the _current_ folder (as opposed to the same folder as the `.tex`), so your `\graphicspath` line should be `\graphicspath{{../DocumentationBuild/}}`, because that's where the `.pdf` is

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik well for that no graphicspath is needed at all, so the question is if it should fail to find anything on the graphics path but then successfully find the pdf in the current directory as it would if the graphicspath was not there

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But the pdf file is not in the current directory. The `.tex` is inside `<root>/Documentation` and the pdf inside `<root>/DocumentationBuild`, so there's no way to find that without `\graphicspath`...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik no the "current directory" is the working directory of the process (and looking at the OP's bat file that is the same for both runs). Thst is why (as the OP says) it works if you remove the`\graphicspath`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah. Well, the build script is wrong to start with (so not my fault :).  The third line should probably read `pdflatex ../Documentation/MyDocument.tex`.  If I change that, everything works fine.  I think OP's getting something wrong with the directories...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik oh that has been changed by an edit, yes it's certainly wrong as it is now.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks for pointing this out, I must have accidentally changed it when I corrected the folder structure.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle as it is only an issue of ```\includegraphics```, I added a setup which is simpler to understand and maybe more realistic, as it is possible to have a graphics name that is also the name of a ```*.tex``` file in another folder, depending on your setup. The problem remains the same, however now removing the ```\graphicspath``` is not a solution anymore.
And I found out, that the double file name has to have a ```*.tex``` extension, with ```*.log``` for example it works.
And my last observation: It is independent of the order of Folder1 and Folder2

Comment: @TobiBS Ah, ok, now I can reproduce the problem.  Indeed, something feels wrong about this.  The existence of `image.tex` in one folder (that is not included as a graphics file) should not prevent `image.pdf` in the other folder from being included...  I'll investigate

Comment: Thanks @PhelypeOleinik and sorry for the confusion. Getting to the point in an MWE is not always simple.

Comment: @TobiBS Please try the patch in this file: https://pastebin.com/raw/ycgrFe79 (should be in the preamble, after loading `graphicx`)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik indeed, this fixes it! However this is a level of TeX I am not able to understand. ;-)

Comment: @TobiBS see the helpful rephrasing here https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60150668#60150668

Comment: @TobiBS The gist of the problem is:  1) You ask for `image`; 2) `image.tex` is found (because Knuth thought it would be a good idea to create assumed extensions) inside `Folder2`, so `./Folder2/` is prepended to the image name (`image.pdf` is not considered because `.pdf` cannot be an implied extension as far as TeX knows); 3) since the file name (`./Folder2/image`) has no extension, try all possible extensions; 4) find none and scream in terror. cont'd

Comment: @TobiBS Adding `./Folder2/` to the file name at that stage seems to be too early, so in the patch I remove the added path.  I will have to test if this doesn't break anything else before I push that as a bug fix

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I am sorry for Ulrike when reading this! Somewhat I am glad that I reached a level of understanding LaTeX, that I was confident enough to post this and I am so grateful that there are people like you that understand LaTeX on the next level so it can be fixed. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was due to a change to LaTeX's filename parser and the (very specific) combination of factors in your case.  You have two files with the same name in different paths (both in `\graphicspath` and neither in a path searched by kpse), and you asked for a file without extension.  Since TeX (unfortunately) understands `image` and `image.tex` to be the same file, it finds `image.tex` and LaTeX's filename parser prepends the path `Folder2/` to the name.  That however makes LaTeX unable to find `Folder1/image.pdf`.

This issue is now fixed in the development version (PR [#777](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/pull/777)), and will be available in the 2022-06-01 release.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the explanation and even more the fix! I am amazed that after 17 years of using LaTeX I found a bug.